# Gremlin java set vertex label throws ClassCastException

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to use Gremlin java to create a vertex if vertex id not exist and set label,
first I try this:

```
GraphTraversalSource graph = TinkerGraph.open().traversal();
graph.V("0").fold().coalesce(__.unfold(),__.addV()).property(T.label, "0").next()
```

but throws exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.T$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

then I try this:

```
GraphTraversalSource graph = TinkerGraph.open().traversal();
graph.V("0").fold().coalesce(__.unfold(),__.addV().property(T.label, "0")).next()
```

This works.

Wonder why first piece of code not working.
For my use case, I need to do it in first way which to decide property later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the label on an already existing vertex. In the second case you add the label as part of the vertex creation.

Comment: I know label can't be changed once created, but from exception I don't think that is the reason, vertex should not be created until call next()

Comment: The exception is because the property step only expects a string key name at that point in the traversal. The vertex flows out of the coalesce step and by that time only named properties can be added. You will see this same behavior in the Gremlin console. This is the expected behavior.